# How to use macros in qlik view

Tags: macros, qlikview

I just started with qlik view macros just wanted to ask is there any library file or API need to install/add to use macros.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to install to use macros. Just code your macro in the Module Editor (Ctrl-m).

Be aware that there are some restrictions on macro usage in the Server environment (see Ref Guide section "Macros on QlikView Server"). I also recommend that before creating a macro to perform a function, check if the function is provided by QlikView Actions. Actions are written in native code and generally perform better and are more stable.

Comment: Thank you Rob for your suggestion. Will start with the work.